# How to make links through own PHP framework

Tags: php, hyperlink, frameworks

I have my own made PHP Framework where the links in the browser are recognized like this.(my folder is called pro and it is stored in htdocs folder)

localhost/pro/data/entry

data: controller
entry: action

PHP Developers who use frameworks are familiar with this, and I can use this method without any problem. But the problems come when I want to make normal anchor links to documents, pages or stylesheets. When i do a normal link like this:

```
<a href="localhost/pro/application/view/data/css/style.css>
```

The browser considers controllers and actions and I need that they are seen like normal relative links?

How can i make normal relative anchor links without the browser to consider the controllers and actions.

Comment: Sorry if I am being rude, but you are trying to create a CMS without knowing the basics of HTML.
Do you want to link to a stylesheet (<link> tag) ? URL should start with `//localhost` `http://localhost`, or simply `/pro/...`

Answer (score 0):

Remove "localhost" and thats an absolute path.

```
    <a href="/pro/application/view/data/css/style.css">
```

And if you want it relative to the script path ( let's supose its on the view folder ).

```
    <a href="./data/css/style.css">
```